Reading on incomparable Turing degrees
I remember seeing in grad school a very nice proof that there were two incomparable Turing degrees by progressively constructing two sequences that couldn't be computed from each other. Can anyone recommend me a text that has an accessible presentation of such a proof?

Do you know the priority method? It can be used to construct two Turing incomparable sets, which is similar to your question: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-60322-8_2

Any book on computability theory should have such a thing (e.g. Soare's book). You don't need a priority argument if you don't are about them being c.e. degrees... the keywords are "Kleene-Post" or "finite extension"

On p. 163 of the late Barry Cooper's Computability Theory (CRC 2004), you'll find a proof of Theorem 10.6.3 (which he attributes to Kleene and Post):

There exist Turing degrees $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ such
that $\mathbf{a} \not\leq \mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{b} \not\leq \mathbf{a}$.

I like Cooper's text a lot, finding it very approachable when I tackled it.

If you just want two Turing-incomparable sequences you can build them explicitly like this: let $(\Phi_e)_{e\in\mathbb{N}}$ be an enumeration of all computable functions. We try to build two infinite binary sequences $A$ and $B$ in stages (recall that binary sequences and subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ are in bijection so you can think of them the way it is more comfortable to you). At each stage s, we only have two finite strings $A_s$ and $B_s$. We start with both $A_0$ and $B_0$ being the empty string.
Since, in the end, we want $A$ and $B$ be Turing-incomparable, we just ensure that every computable function with oracle $A$ will not compute $B$, and vice versa.
In the even stages we ensure that $A$ does not compute $B$. More precisely, at stage $s=2e$ we guarantee that $\Phi_e^A\neq B$. To do so, we search for $n>0$ and a string $\sigma$ such that $\Phi_e^{A_s\smallfrown 0^n} \neq B\smallfrown \sigma$, where $\smallfrown$ denotes the concatenation. The trick is that at some point we will find such $n$ and $\sigma$, as otherwise we could extend $B_s$ with a non computable string, and $A_s\smallfrown 0^\mathbb{N}$ would compute it (which is impossible). Observe that such search is not computable though (for example, if $\Phi_e^{A_s\smallfrown 0^n}$ doesn't halt, you will need an oracle to know that $\Phi_e^{A_s\smallfrown 0^n} \neq B\smallfrown \sigma$ is satisfied). At this point you define $A_{s+1}:=A_s\smallfrown 0^n$, $B_{s+1}:=B_s\smallfrown \sigma$ and go to the next stage. This guarantees that the $A$ will not compute $B$ via $\Phi_e$.
In the odd stages, you do the same thing but swap the roles of $A$ and $B$.
This is a simple construction that does not require the use of priority arguments, or more sophisticated techniques. If you want to read more, a standard reference is
Soare, Robert I., Recursively enumerable sets and degrees. A study of computable functions and computably generated sets, Perspectives in Mathematical Logic. Berlin etc.: Springer-Verlag. XVIII, 437 p.; DM 68.00 (1987). ZBL0623.03042.
You may also take a look at
Soare, Robert I., Turing computability. Theory and applications, Theory and Applications of Computability. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 978-3-642-31932-7/hbk; 978-3-642-31933-4/ebook). xxxvi, 263 p. (2016). ZBL1350.03001.
Odifreddi, Piergiorgio, Classical recursion theory. The theory of functions and sets of natural numbers., Studies in Logic and the Foundations of Mathematics. 125. Amsterdam etc.: North-Holland. xvii, 668 p. (1992). ZBL0744.03044.
